# ESC doesn't unselect my selection

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

It's impossible to unselect my selection by pressing `ESC` (It keeps the selection I had made)

I want that when I press `ESC`, that it unselects everything. Is this possible?

This behavior is present in Visual Studio too

Answer (score 1):

VIKASH_DASH's answer is on the right track, but overriding `Escape`'s functionality without [context](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html#structure-of-a-key-binding) is going to *hurt some feelings.* `Escape` is a rather dignified key; take a look at `Preferences -> Key Bindings – Default` and you'll see that `Escape` has *six* important, er, escape-related functions. You definitely wouldn't want to overwrite all of them all of the time!

Thankfully, Sublime Text's keybindings can have [contexts](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html#structure-of-a-key-binding). Coupled with some sneaky usage of the [move command](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/sublime-text-2/reference/commands.html) (have you noticed that hitting `Left` or `Right` effectively deselects everything?) you can create a keybinding to add to `Preferences -> Key Bindings – User` that **only executes if you have something selected** and **doesn't clobber Escape's other functions:**

```
{ "keys": ["escape"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }
    ]
}
```

The `"forward": true` argument to the `move` command will move your cursor to the end of the current selection before deselecting (it will also split your cursor if you have multiple selections, just mash it again to escape from that as well!). To move to the beginning instead, change `"forward": true}` to `"forward": false}`. Instead of acting almost exactly like `Right`, `Escape` is now a glorified `Left`!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can't I just let the cursor stay where it was when pushing `ESC` and not let him go to the end or beginning of my selection?

Comment: @Ozkan Do you mean you have multiple selections? A block of selected text is defined by its edges, meaning relevant cursor positions are at either end. I'm not sure where else the cursor could reasonably go when you press `ESC`. Can you clarify?

Comment: You are right. Indeed when I have multiple selections. I search something that appears a lot times, I do `Alt``TAB`, and when I press `ESC` it jumps to somewhere else...

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice [deselect package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Deselect) - 
it doesn't move the cursor

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect! It didn't work out of the box for me though. I had to use this keybinding: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/select-all-to-view-invisible-characters/3927/9

Answer (score 0):

its in In

> preferences->key bindings usr ..

use put these code hope its works;

```
[
{ "keys": ["escape"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "eof", "extend": false} },
]
```

Comment: It deselects but moves to the end of file automatically.